# Only show decimal for non-integers in Liquid

Tags: liquid

Pretty simple one I think, but can't work out if it is possible. I have a number in a Liquid template that should only have a decimal place if it isn't an integer. Unfortunately the database stores a float (which I cannot change), so my only option is to try do this in Liquid. Essentially if the number is `5.5` I want it to output that. However it the number is `5.0` I want it to output `5`.

I can't see a way of checking whether a number is a float or not. Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be achieved by using some of the [liquid filters](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/).

First you use `split` to break the number up by the decimal point, then `last` to check if the last number is `0`. Finally use `remove` to get rid of the `.0`.

For example:

```
{% assign result = 5.0 %}
{% assign splitResult = result | split: '.' %}
{% if splitResult.last == '0' %}
  {% assign newResult = result | remove: '.0'  %}
{% else %}
  {% assign newResult = result %}
{% endif %}

{{ newResult}}
```

In this case `{{ newResult }}` will output `5`.

Hope that helps!